# Как получать разницу между массивами javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть явная проблема, не могу получить достоверное и стабильное решение.
У меня есть два массива такого типа

```
[{id:1, name:"Vasya"}, {id:2, name:"Vova"}]

[{id:1, name:"Vasya"}, {id:2, name:"Vova"}, {id:3, name:"Bob"}]
```

Я изменяю эти массивы и получаю разницу между ними таким методом

```
result_search = $(arr1).not(arr2).get();
```

Но результат верен только первый раз затем когда изменяются индексы то разница уже не верная. Может есть метод иначе получать разницу массивов и при этом не связанную с индексами?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась использованием такой функции

```
$.each(arr, function(index){
    if(!arr2[index]) {
        result_search.push(arr[index]);
    }
});
```

Но оказывается что и этот метод аналогично работает

```
result_search = $(arr1).not(arr2).get();
```

Просто когда я удалял значения то использовал функцию delete, при этом сохранялся индекс а значение уничтожалось, я применил slice и все получилось

```
data_cache_edit.splice(i,1);
```